# How can I check for identical items and update a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an amount of items in a list or `list_1`. Each item is a row from a database. 
An import of these items is going to happen on another list, or `list_2`.  `list_2` already contains content of the same type.
Is there a way to make this happen so that only those items that are not present in `list_2` get imported?

Note that the original order must be retained in `list_2` and the new items are to be imported on top of that original order.  The order is important because `list_2` actually is a concurrentqueue.  So, the content of `list_1` should be updated somehow (clearing the duplicates) before I can start importing it into `list_2`.  The actual import into `list_2` (queue) is not a problem, it's the way to clean up `list_1` that interests me. Thanks.

Comment: Don't your items have IDs?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;
//...

var strippedList1 = list_1.Except(list_2);
```

To make this work, you need to make sure that your objects implement `Equals`/`GetHashcode`

Comment: thanks. not sure what you mean with 'objects implement Equals/GetHashcode'.

Comment: I'm assuming you have `list_2 is List<SomeClass>`. You need to ensure that `SomeClass` overrides `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashcode`. Otherwise the only way .NET can compare two objects is to compare if both objects are references to the same physical object in memory, which is probably not helpful in your scenario.

Comment: list_1 and list_2 are indeed types 'List<SomeClass>'. i set resultlist also as type 'List<SomeClass>'.

Comment: so how can i ensure that 'SomeClass' overrides Object.Equals and Object.GetHashcode?

Comment: That's pretty basic C# concept, you may want to get up to speed ASAP. Here's some bedtime read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

please look at my below code it may help you

```
        List<string> l = new List<string>();
        l.Add("1");
        l.Add("2");
        List<string> l1 = new List<string>();
        l1.Add("1");
        var abc = l.Except(l1);
```